# Seek for a better way to set different layouts for phone and tablet in landscape mode

Tags: android, layout

In my android app, I want to load different layouts for phone and tablet in landscape mode, the layout in tablet landscape is the same as portrait in both.
So my layout folder in res is like layout(default), layout-land(for phone landscape), layout-sw600dp-land(for tablet landscape). But  layout(default) and layout-sw600dp-land(for tablet landscape) is totally the same. I want to optimize this, any help is appreciated.

I plan to use layout alias, but I cannot understand the sample code in website, what I doubt is if I need to load the layout in the code, which xml file should I use?

Comment: the layout in tablet landscape is the same as portrait in both -> No need to create layout-sw600dp-land(for tablet landscape).

Comment: But I create layout-land(for phone landscape) , if without layout-sw600dp-land, the tablet landscape will be the same as phone, this is not what I want.

Comment: I have one patch for it. You have to create two layouts with different names and  one for phone and second for tablet. In your activity you have to check first isTablet then you should use tablet layout.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think this is a better way, but thanks any way